# Why does the Rancher Security Group use TCP Port 10256?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rancher, ports

What does TCP 10256 do and where is to documented. According to the [*"Rancher AWS EC2 Security Grouplink"*](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.5/en/installation/requirements/ports/#rancher-aws-ec2-security-group) it's open. But I don't see any documentation on port 10256 elsewhere.

It's also documented on the similar [*"Azure machine config"*](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.6/en/cluster-provisioning/rke-clusters/node-pools/azure/azure-machine-config/)

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](https://github.com/rancher/rke/issues/212) it is used for `kubeproxy`.

> The Kubernetes network proxy runs on each node. This reflects services as defined in the Kubernetes API on each node and can do simple TCP, UDP, and SCTP stream forwarding or round robin TCP, UDP, and SCTP forwarding across a set of backends. Service cluster IPs and ports are currently found through Docker-links-compatible environment variables specifying ports opened by the service proxy. There is an optional addon that provides cluster DNS for these cluster IPs. The user must create a service with the apiserver API to configure the proxy.
>
> [...]
>
> `--healthz-bind-address ipport     Default: 0.0.0.0:10256`
>
> The IP address with port for the health check server to serve on (set to '0.0.0.0:10256' for all IPv4 interfaces and '[::]:10256' for all IPv6 interfaces). Set empty to disable. This parameter is ignored if a config file is specified by --config.

**References**
[kube-proxy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-proxy/)